# download and pipe sql to psql

Tags: bash, curl, pipe, postgresql

How can I do this in one step?

Download backup command:

```
curl http://s3.aws.com/backup.sql
```

Restore backup command:

```
sudo -u postgres psql <PIPE-THE-OUTPUT-OF-PREVIOUS-COMMAND>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If both command are working, you should try

```
curl -s http://s3.aws.com/backup.sql | sudo -u postgres psql
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I just stumbled upon during a search (it was the top of the results) and it does not look like any of the answers are correct according to the `postgres` manual.

The manual suggests passing the `-f -` as an option to `psql` and then piping over `stdin` what ever you want. Quoting the manual for 9.4:

> If filename is - (hyphen), then standard input is read until an EOF
>   indication or \q meta-command. Note however that Readline is not used
>   in this case (much as if -n had been specified).
>
> Using this option is subtly different from writing psql < filename. In
>   general, both will do what you expect, but using -f enables some nice
>   features such as error messages with line numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way:

```
sudo -u postgres psql --file <(curl -s http://s3.aws.com/backup.sql)
```